# Getting 404 not found error while importing the fullcalender library in LWC . Note : i am using the library from (https://fullcalendar.io/)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

```
import { LightningElement ,track} from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import myCalender from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/myCalender";
import getAvailableTimeSlots from '@salesforce/apex/AlmanacService.getAvailableTimeSlots';

export default class CalenderTest04 extends LightningElement {
    
    @track allEvents = [];
    @track selectedEvent = undefined;

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('Inside renderCallback()');
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, myCalender + '/packages/core/main.css'),
            loadScript(this, myCalender + '/packages/core/main.js'),
            loadStyle(this, myCalender + '/packages/core/main.min.css'),
            loadScript(this, myCalender + '/packages/core/main.min.js'),
        ])
        .then(() => {
        // Initialise the calendar configuration
        this.almnacTimeslot();
        console.log("inside then success block");
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.error({
            message: 'Not Loading FullCalendarJS',
            error
        });
        })
}
initialiseFullCalendarJs(){

    const ele = this.template.querySelector('div.fullcalendarjs');
    $(ele).fullCalendar({
    
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next,today',
        center: 'title',
        //right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,listMonth,listWeek'
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      weekends: false ,
      themeSystem : 'standard',
      defaultView:'agendaWeek',
      defaultDate: new Date(), // default day is today
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events : this.allEvents, //to be developed
      dragScroll : false,
      droppable: false,
      weekNumbers : true,
      weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
      weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
      buttonIcons: true,
     
      // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick
      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
      alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());
      if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change? ")) {
        revertFunc();
        }
      },
      eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Event Clicked '+event.title)
        this.selectedEvent =  event;
      },
      dayClick :function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        jsEvent.preventDefault();
        
      },
      eventMouseover : function(event, jsEvent, view) {
      }
    });
    }
    
    
    
    /* ==========      Used for     ============*/
    get almnacTimeslot(){
      let returnValue =[];
        getAvailableTimeSlots({
        serviceType:"tv",
        startDate:"2022-01-01",
        endDate:"2022-01-30"
        }).then(result =>{  
            if(Object.values(result).length> 0 ) {
            Object.values(result).forEach(function(currentItem){
              console.log(currentItem);
              Object.entries(currentItem).forEach(function(item){
                console.log(item);
                Object.values(item).forEach(function(innerItem){
                  console.log("innerItem");
                  console.log(innerItem);
                  var element = {};
                  if((innerItem.capacity - innerItem.booked) >= 1 ) {
                    element={
                      id :innerItem.id,
                      start :innerItem.startDateTime,
                      end :innerItem.endDateTime,
                      //title :,      //will be displayed in the event
                      //description:,
                      extendedProps:{
                        booked:innerItem.booked,
                        capacity:innerItem.capacity
                      },
                      backgroundColor: "rgb(169,169,169)",
                    }
                  }
                  else {
                    element={
                      id :innerItem.id,
                      start :innerItem.startDateTime,
                      end :innerItem.endDateTime,
                      //title :,      //will be displayed in the event
                      //description:,
                      extendedProps:{
                        booked:innerItem.booked,
                        capacity:innerItem.capacity
                      },
                      backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
                      editable:false,
                    }
                  } 
                returnValue.push(element);
                });
              });
            });
            this.allEvents=({},returnValue);
            console.log(returnValue); 
            console.log("this.allEvents");
            console.log(this.allEvents);
          }
          this.initialiseFullCalendarJs();
          this.error = undefined; 
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
         }).finally(()=>{
          this.initialiseFullCalendarJs();
        })
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.selectedEvent = undefined;
      }

      get serviceTypes() {
        return [
            { label: 'TV', value: 'tv' },
            { label: 'BB', value: 'bb' },
        ];
    }
    
    handleChange(event) {
      this.value = event.detail.value;
      console.log(event.detail.value);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Could it be a typo in your import? Is the static resource really "myCalender" with the incorrect spelling of Calendar? Also is it set up as a JS file? It looks like you expect it to be [a ZIP file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_resources). But you can't expect additional JS files required to be imported in the one you load to also be loaded from that ZIP... you need to flatten it out. At least that's what I remember.

Comment: Take a look at this new [LWC recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/pull/609).